# How to prove A → N from A and (A ∨ B) → N in FOL

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have the following premises:
A and 
(A ∨ B) → N

How can I prove A → N from this in a formal proof using FOL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1. A \quad Premise\\
2. (A \lor B) \rightarrow N \quad Premise}{
\fitch{
3. A \quad \ Assume}
{4. A \lor B \quad \lor \ Intro \ 3\\
5. N \quad \rightarrow \ Elim \ 2,4}\\
6. A \rightarrow N \quad \rightarrow \ Intro \ 3-5}$

Note that this proof never used premise 1, as indeed $(A \lor B) \rightarrow N$ follows from $A \rightarrow n$ alone; it is an example of the valid inference pattern called Strengthening the Antecedent.  Are you sure $A$ was an actual premise?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

*Proof.* Assume $A$ and $(A\lor B)\implies N$ by *addition* it follows that $A\lor B$ is true and by *modus ponens* we can reason that $N$ must be true consequently $A\implies N$.

$\blacksquare$